# usage of glDepthTest isn't clear

Tags: opengl

I wrote a code with glDepthTest and i try to understand what is the formula for projective Z-buffer value.

I run this code:

```
  #define CUBE_SIDE_SIZE   512.0f
  #define Z_SIZE   -0.25f
  #define WINDOW_WIDTH 1024
  #define WINDOW_HEIGHT    768
  void init(void)
  {
   glViewport(0,0,WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT);
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity(); 
   glOrtho(0,WINDOW_WIDTH,0,WINDOW_HEIGHT, -1, 1);
  }

  void display(void)
  {
   GLfloat readPixel;

   glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
   glClearDepth(0.8);   
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity();

   glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);  
   glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

   glBegin(GL_QUADS);

   glColor3f(1, 0, 0);

   glVertex3f(0, 0, Z_SIZE);
   glVertex3f(0, CUBE_SIDE_SIZE, Z_SIZE);
   glVertex3f(CUBE_SIDE_SIZE, CUBE_SIDE_SIZE, Z_SIZE);
   glVertex3f(CUBE_SIDE_SIZE, 0, Z_SIZE);
   glEnd();
   glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
   glFlush();
   glutSwapBuffers();
   glReadPixels(0,0,1.0,1.0,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &readPixel);
}
```

The value of readPixel in this case is 0.625, so i think the calculation is: 
 Z-buffer value = (farZ - Z_value) / (farZ - nearZ) 
 
in my case:

[1 - (-0.25)] / ]1 - (- 1)] = 1.25 / 2 = 0.625

But when i do these changes:
 1. #define Z_SIZE 0.25f
 2. glOrtho(0,WINDOW_WIDTH,0,WINDOW_HEIGHT, 0, 1);

I get the value 0.8 in readPixel, it's like the depth test falied, but if i calculated the Z-buffer value it should be equals to (1 - 0.25) / (1 - 0) = 0.75 which is less then 0.8 (clear depth value).

Can you explain me this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

> so i think the calculation is: Z-buffer value = (farZ - Z_value) / (farZ - nearZ)

Nope. There's an additional division factor `1/w` getting into it. Which means that the depth buffer values don't follow a linear progression. They're monotonic though.

The calculation of NDC coordinates as as following

```
pos_view = ModelviewMatrix · vertex_position
pos_projected = ProjectionMatrix · pos_view
pos_clipped = clip_prmitive( pos_projected )
pos_NDC = pos_clipped.xyz / pos_clipped.w
```

pos_NDC.z is your depth buffer value. For all practical means to understand the transformation steps you can regard `clip_primitive(…)` as an identity transform, i.e. things go unchanged through it.

Comment: I thought that the w is only used in frustrum and not in ortho.

Comment: @user2877748: It's always used, but using a ortho projection w=1.

Comment: So the Z buffer values using ortho and without any transforms is changing linear? If yes, does the written formula is OK? Thanks

Comment: @user2877748: That's indeed the case. However since you didn't specify from which buffer to read (front or back) you could simply be reading garbage. Also the depth buffer contents are not guaranteed to be valid after a buffer swap. So I suggest you do a `glFinish(); glReadBuffer(GL_BACK); glReadPixels(…)` before `SwapBuffers`.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I tried your suggestion, but it doesn't help at all. The depth buffer value is still 0.8